# DbContext Save Changes adding data even if model is not change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I call DbContext.SaveChanges() it adds data to some table that I don't want.

To explain further here are my models:

**WorkItem**

```
public class WorkItem 
{
    public long WorkItemID { get;set }
    /* Some properties*/

    public virtual IList<WorkItemSchedule> WorkItemSchedules {get;set;}
}
```

**WorkItemSchedule**

```
public class WorkItemSchedule
{
    public long WorkItemScheduleID {get;set;}
    public int PhaseID { get; set; }
    /* Some properties*/

    public virtual WorkItem WorkItem { get; set; }
    public virtual Phase Phase { get; set; }
}
```

**Phase**

```
public class Phase
{
    public int PhaseID {get;set;}

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public string PhaseName {get;set;}
    /* Some prperies*/
}
```

I get error when save changes of DbContext from my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate(WorkItemScheduleViewModel viewModel)
{
    WorkItem workItem = viewModel.WorkItem;
    db.WorkItems.Add(workItem);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "WorkItem");
}
```

**Inner Exception is:**

> *Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Phase' with unique index 'IX_PhaseName'. The duplicate key value is (Analysis).\r\nThe
>   statement has been terminated.*

My question is, I don't do anything in Phase model. Hence, why the DBContext monitor changes (add) for this. Please help. Thanks,

**EDIT**

```
public class WorkItemManagerContext : DbContext
{
    public WorkItemManagerContext()
        : base("WorkItemManagerConnString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkItemSchedule> WorkItemSchedules { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Here's the inner exception I am getting:

`Attaching an entity of type 'WorkItemManager.Models.WorkItemSchedule' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.`

Comment: How `WorkItemScheduleViewModel` looks like?

Comment: It's just a viewmodel which collects workitemschedule, I think this has nothing to do with the error because I didn't do any changes in the dbcontext on that.

Answer (score 0):

The `DbSet.Add()` method marks the entire object graph (the entity and all its related entities) as "Added" which will always cause inserts. I suggest always using the `DbSet.Attach()` method instead as it makes no assumptions about the state of the object graph and expects you to manually set the state of each entity using `DbContext.Entry(entityVariable).State`.

You could use `DbSet.Add()` if you are absolutely certain that the entire object graph is new and should trigger inserts, but I think it's better to avoid it.

The following code causes the DbContext to start tracking the entity and marks the `workItem` as Added, but does not cause inserts for the `WorkItemSchedules` collection.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate(WorkItemScheduleViewModel viewModel)
{
    WorkItem workItem = viewModel.WorkItem;
    db.WorkItems.Attach(workItem);
    db.Entry(workItem).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "WorkItem");
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676

Comment: WorkItemManagerContext does not contain a definition for 'Attach' :( I'll updated my question so that you can see.

Comment: Attach is on the DbSet. I updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks!! I think this is the correct answer now with my problem. But I've got another problem now, by default, WorkItem.WorkItemID is set to '0', how can I correctly create a WorkItemID that is valid and increment to the last? Thanks again.

Comment: After you call `db.SaveChanges()`, the `workItem.WorkItemID` should have the database-generated value in it.

Comment: I mean, I get InvalidOperationException from db.WorkItems.Attach(workItem)

Comment: check my edit, I included the inner exception I am getting. Thanks,

Comment: Ah, you're not working with a fresh DbContext. You could do as the error message suggests and use the `DbSet.Add()` method then manually set the state of each WorkItemSchedule using `DbContext.Entry().State`. Or you could make sure you new up a fresh DbContext for each operation instead of keeping the same one around in your session.